# Impact of unsued assemblies in project reference

Tags: .net, clr

What will be the impact, if an application has unused DLL reference (framework dll) added to the project during compilation?

Like, will it increase the assembly size? will it load those DLLs at runtime? etc

This question is not about optimization. This is to better understand the .NET infrastructure.

Comment: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c6d4ee69-7a82-4dba-bb00-ebb2fd6ab9a9/)

Comment: @ColeJohnson - But the JIT should be loading it only when it is requiring the dll right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the C# compiler only puts assembly references in the final assembly for assemblies that contain types that are actually used in your code.  The only impact of adding unused assemblies is a very slight slowdown of the compilation itself.

You can see this for yourself with ildasm.exe.  Run it on the final assembly, double-click the manifest and look for the `.assembly` directives.

This is heavily optimized at runtime as well, assemblies are loaded by the just-in-time compiler.  Which only does so if you actually call a method of a type in that assembly.

Comment: Thanks. I verified this as you mentioned with ildasm and what you said is correct.

Comment: Did you run this with optimizations off. Because when I did, I saw the unused directives.

Comment: I did this in C# 4.0 in debug mode.

Comment: What about application size? Will it increase?

Answer (score 1):

According to an [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c6d4ee69-7a82-4dba-bb00-ebb2fd6ab9a9/) Q&A, referencing it **will** increase your assembly size, however, `using` statements are evaluated on compile time (see below).

---

At runtime, the JIT "compiler" will be dispatched to hook the DLL. The reason behind the ~1KB increase in file size is because of the ~1KB needed to store reference information. It **will** slow down your startup time as it hooks each DLL, but runtime will not be impacted. The startup time difference will be so minute, I suggest taking a look at [this article on CodingHorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html). Unless this is to be deployed onto an embedded system, I would not worry about this. On application close, the JIT "compiler" will unload the DLL and free the required resources.

---

About the `using` statements. At compile time, the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void DoNothing(int nil)
    { }
}
```

will be translated into:

```
using System;
public class MyClass
{
    public static void DoNothing(Int32 nil)
    { }
}
```

which will further be translated into:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void DoNothing(System.Int32 nil)
    { }
}
```

Comment: This is not about micro optimization. This is to better understand the .NET Infrastructure.  So, the hooking up of DLL will happen at application startup or as and when JIT needs to dispatch that call to the DLL?

Comment: @Ramesh yes. It will dispatch to hook, but until you call a function in the Dll, it will just be dead weight.

Comment: @Ramesh the reason behind the MO link is to show that with todays processors, the startup time will be VERY minute.

Comment: also this is not regarding using statements. I understand using statements are only meant to ease the developers life from typing the Fully qualified name for every type.

Comment: So, to understand it - assemblies will be loaded on app startup (not on usage) and will remain loaded until the App domain unloads

Comment: To me Hans answer seems to be right. I verified this with ildasm.